# A => Class[A] using ClassTag?

Tags: scala, reflection

Looking at [ClassTag#runtimeClass](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest@runtimeClass:Class[_]), it has a return type of `Class[_]`, i.e. a `Class` with, as I understand, a wildcard parameter.

I tried to implement a method: `A => ClassTag[A]`:

```
import scala.reflect._

scala> def f[A](x: A)(implicit ev: ClassTag[A]) = ev.runtimeClass
f: [A](x: A)(implicit ev: scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])Class[_]
```

But, the output of the `def`'s definition is, as the docs show, `Class[_]`.

Is it possible to change `f` such that its return type is `Class[A]`? If not, then why is it not possible?

Comment: Maybe `ev.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[A]]`?

Comment: I didn't mention, but I would like to avoid asInstanceOf if possible.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Not possible here unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you change the signature of `f`, your only option is to cast the `Class[_]` to a `Class[A]`.

There is literally only one method in the entire Scala standard library that returns a `Class[A]`, and that is `classOf`. `f[A]` cannot be re-written to use `classOf[A]` since it is a special compiler method and is incompatible with generic type parameters that may not be classes. You would simply get an error:

```
scala> def f[A: ClassTag](x: A) = classOf[A]
<console>:10: error: class type required but A found
       def f[A: ClassTag](x: A) = classOf[A]
                                          ^
```

The best you can get without casting is using `x.getClass`, but that will return a `Class[_ <: A]` (no `ClassTag` needed).

```
scala> def f[A](x: A): Class[_ <: A] = x.getClass
f: [A](x: A)Class[_ <: A]

scala> f(1)
res8: Class[_ <: Int] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> f(List(1, 2, 3))
res9: Class[_ <: List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

You might ask, why `_ <: A`?

The answer to that question is also the reason why your definition of `f` doesn't really make sense. If `A` is an `Int`, it makes sense to be able to return a `Class[A]` because `Int` is a class. But what  if `A` is a `List[Int]`? `List[Int]` is not a class, it's a type. The class is `List`, but `A != List`, therefore we cannot return a `Class[A]` consistently. We *can*, however, have an upper-bound of `A` on the type parameter of `Class`.